# How do you select a transparency color of a JPEG in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-3.0

In XNA 2.0 I remembered that to specify a color transparency there was a property to set in the property windows of your JPEG. Now I'm in XNA 3.0 and I don't find this property anymore ! Any idea ?

Comment: Do not use JPEG for this! JPEG will changes the colors of your image so your color key will be 'spotty' (if at all present). Rather use PNG 24, or PNG 32 (and using 32 will save you from the color key in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color key property is still there. Check this [XNA Docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975255.aspx), maybe that will help.

Comment: What a shame, I didn't see the [+] in front of the content processor in my property window -_-